# Why does SQS wait 10 seconds when calling ReceiveMessage?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-sqs

In my `ReceiveMessage` call to Amazon SQS I have set `WaitTimeSeconds` to `0` and I have configured the queue to have a `WaitTimeout` of `0`.

Why are calls always taking a little longer than 10 seconds? That suggests that a wait period of 10 seconds is being used although I meant to turn that off.

The .NET SDK queries the queue roughly 200 times during that period without any delay:

[image]

So maybe there is no 10 second wait but simply this flood of requests. Maybe there is rampant retry with a 10 second maximum duration? I set the retry count to `0` as well without result. Also, the service responses (not shown here) are HTTP-200 with no error message in body. The body simply has no messages.

Code:

```
using (var sqsClient = new AmazonSQSClient(new AmazonSQSConfig() { MaxErrorRetry = 0 }))
{
    var receiveMessageResponse = sqsClient.ReceiveMessage(new ReceiveMessageRequest() {
        QueueUrl = queueUrl,
        MaxNumberOfMessages = maxNumberOfMessages,
        WaitTimeSeconds = 0
    });
}
```

Queue config:

```
Name:   _________   Default Visibility Timeout  30 seconds
URL:    https://sqs.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/_________   Message Retention Period    14 days
ARN:    arn:aws:sqs:eu-west-1:_________ Maximum Message Size    256 KB
Created:    2016-01-28 _________    Receive Message Wait Time   0 seconds
Last Updated:   2016-01-28 _________    Messages Available (Visible):   0
Delivery Delay  0 seconds   Messages in Flight (Not Visible):   0
Messages Delayed:   0
```

Comment: *"I tried to turn that off."* ... You *tried*?  Does that mean you had it set, previously?

Comment: It is configured to 0 still.

Comment: @tster code edited. The web.config is empty apart from the secrets.

Comment: Can you create a stand-alone reproduction with all the other code removed which exhibits this behavior?

Comment: This is the full code. No other global configurations have been made. I have left out setting `AttributeNames` in the request since I doubt that contributes. @tster

Comment: Was this ever resolved?